# Java intersection of lines and find its coordinate and its nearest neighbour to the right or below

Tags: java, intersection, nearest-neighbor

I am struggling to find a way to to get the nearest point of the coordinate x and coordinate Y to the right and below if they exist else print nothing.

```
public class CheckForIntersection {

    double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4, a, b, c, d, e, f, checkLinear, x, y;

    CheckForIntersection(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.x3 = x3;
        this.y3 = y3;
        this.x4 = x4;
        this.y4 = y4;

        checkintersection();
    }

    public double getx() {
        return x;
    }

    public double gety() {
        return y;
    }

    public void checkintersection() {
        a = y1 - y2;
        b = -(x1 - x2);
        c = y3 - y4;
        d = -(x3 - x4);
        e = (y1 - y2) * x1 - (x1 - x2) * y1;
        f = (y3 - y4) * x3 - (x3 - x4) * y3;

        checkLinear = (a * d) - (b * c);

        x = ((e * d) - (b * f)) / checkLinear;
        y = ((a * f) - (e * c)) / checkLinear;

        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f);
        checknearestNeighbour(x, y);

        if (checkLinear == 0) {
            System.out.println("the intersection is parallel");
        } else {
            System.out.println("X coordinate:" + x + " X coordinate:" + y);
        }
    }
}
```

the result for the follwoing args should be 2.88889, 1.1111.

Comment: i'm basically using linear equation to find the x and y coordinate by giving x1...x4 and y1....y4 and using Cramer’s rule to calculate the intersection point. the part im struggling with is finding the nearest point of those coordinate to the  right or below

Answer (score 2):

Well I assume with "grid" you mean a structure like this:

```
x - x - x
|   |   |   
x - o - o
|   |   |     
o - x - x
```

Where x = node & o = no node 
(assuming equal distances between all intersections)

1. To determine the coordinates of all notes you need a startpoint (coordinate origin).
   This could be top left or bottom left of the grid, up to you to decide.
2. Then you could to loop line by line (one loop for the horizontal lines and one for the elements in each line), checking at each intersection if there is a node (this ofc requires a way to determine intersections). Since it is a grid (same distances) you can run a simple counter for your steps and to determine the coordinates for each intersection in one line. If you finde a node - store these information
3. You can now answer your questions while traversing the grid for efficiency, or do it in a seperate step after you gathered the information.

Comment: since you added extra information after i posted, this might not be what you are looking for

Comment: this seems like a good approach. thank you i will have a go at this.